# Twitter Bootstrap 2.3 Typeahead search element name with character & in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap's typeahead for autocomplete, it works well, but I have one problem in Google Chrome, if I search for a name that includes a "&" then this character is being removed, and I can't search that name, for example H&M.

Is there anyway to fix this? In firefox it works, or if I copy and paste the & character it also works.

The example of Bootstrap has also that problem
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead

As said that happens in Google Chrome for MacOS

Comment: in chrome or in firefox, in windows or mac?

Comment: In your backend, do you have `&` or do you have the proper `&amp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that & and up arrow have the same keycode (38) and bootstrap has the following code:

```
      case 38: // up arrow
      e.preventDefault()
      this.prev()
      break
```

That code removes the & from a search field

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by checking whether the shift key was used in order to differentiate between the up arrow and the ampersand.

```
case 38: // up arrow / ampersand
  // When used with the shiftKey this is actually the ampersand. 
  // Don't prevent default or call prev if the shift key is also pressed
  if (!e.shiftKey) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.prev()
  }
  break
```

I also applied the same check to the down arrow (case 40) since it is also triggered by the left parenthesis.

```
case 40: // down arrow / left parenthesis
  // When used with the shiftKey this is actually the left parenthesis. 
  // Don't prevent default or call next if the shift key is also pressed
  if (!e.shiftKey){
    e.preventDefault()
    this.next()
  }
  break
```